# Any difference between write html decoded str to file and write html binary data directly to a file?

Tags: python, http, binary

Code:

```
from urllib import request
response = request.urlopen('http://www.amazon.com/')
body = response.read()
with open('test.html', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(body)
with open('test2.html', 'w') as f:
  f.write(body.decode('utf-8'))
```

any differences or anything need to pay attention to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way

```
with open('test.html', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(body)
```

simply saves the binary data you downloaded.

The second way

```
with open('test2.html', 'w') as f:
  f.write(body.decode('utf-8'))
```

assumes the data is UTF-8, attempts to decode those UTF-8 bytes to Unicode text, and then re-encodes it to your default file encoding, as specified by `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`. So if the data is *already* UTF-8 it wastefully decodes and re-encodes it. And if it's *not* UTF-8, then it specifies the wrong encoding to decode it with. That will work ok if the file only contains plain 7-bit ASCII data, but otherwise it will give wrong results, or raise `UnicodeDecodeError`.